# Fetching to substring before operator from a dynamic string

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a string like "name = mita and salary> 10000" . Out of which I need to get only name and salary attribute.I am going to have dynamic string on which i need the attribute before operator only. Like here I need to fetch name and salary attribute which r before = and > operator. I can have multiple condition of same type in the string. I can anyone please feasible way to fetch string before operator in Java8
Please find the example strings and expected output as below:

```
String str ="name = 'mita' and salary> 10000" ;
//output expected name, salary

String str1 = "role!= 'software engineer' and salary < 50000 and surname='mitra'";
// output expected role,salary,surname

String str2 = "name= 'dev' and role!= 'software engineer' and salary < 50000 and surname='mitra'";
// output expected name,role,salary,surname
```

Comment: I think you are looking for an SQL parser. You can take a look at some tools like SqlParser, JSqlParser, ZQL, ... If your cases are simple and consists of minimal operators, you may write your own parser (see ANTLR or JavaCC).

Comment: I need to write in java coding only and preferably in java 8-11 version

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: I have tried to split string and fetch substring but that is not working so far. Thats why I looking for some solution on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `split` method of `String` class and `Regex` :

```
String abc = "name = 'mita' and salary> 10000";
List<String> collect = Stream.of(abc.split("and|or"))
                .map(String::trim)
                .map(str -> str.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']")[0])
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(collect);
```

Comment: and what about "or" and what about variables that have numbers in them and what about the attribute coming second and not first?

Comment: @muzzletov : updated for it . multiple delimiters can be added so added ```or``` in answer. also ```regex``` can be made as per our need - updated for digits as well.

Comment: "2=bla", your regex would be wrong then and "bla = blubb" would also only consider the left side

Comment: String abc = "name = 'mita' and salary> 10000";
  Stream.of(abc.split("and|or"))
              .map(String::trim)
              .map(str -> str.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")[0])
              .forEach(System.out::println);///this code is working. Thanks. Could you please suggest how to put the result in an array or list

Comment: @user3009810 : Updated . Please accept it as answer.